# I want to validate application pool identity with a custom account via command line

Tags: powershell, iis

I am currently attempting to use this command:

```
.\appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='cobra.appdelivery.com'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='cobra.appdelivery.com'].processModel.userName: domainname\joshtest /[name='cobra.appdelivery.com'].processModel.password: test1234
```

when I try to do this I get the error that says:

> ERROR (message:Cannot find SITE object with identifier "domainnamejoshtest"

Also I need a way to encrypt the password within the code. I have already created the application pool. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Also can I get tips on how to encrypt the password or make PowerShell prompt for the password anytime I want to run the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it with `Get-Credential`. It'll pop up a dialog box asking for a username and a password. If you're using PowerShell to work with appcmd.exe, you have to change [the way things are quoted](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx) a little bit to make things work without throwing that error you're seeing. Be sure to run PowerShell as an administrator.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$name = $cred.UserName
$encryptedpass = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($cred.Password)
$decryptedpass = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($encryptedpass)
.\appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /"[name='Marketing'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser" /"[name='Marketing'].processModel.userName:$name" /"[name='Marketing'].processModel.password:$decryptedpass"
```

Make sure `appcmd` is in your system paths or run this from the folder where it resides. Also note: If you put in a wrong username and password, it will take it. There is no validation of the input for the username or password. It just applies the setting.

If you want to review the setting run the following and check under [processModel]:

```
.\appcmd list apppool "Marketing" /text:*
```